# A Networked Resource Monitoring Tool for Django

Tags: web-server, django, nginx

I have a django-nginx-gunicorn based server application and I wish to monitor resource trends and analyse performance. Also, I want to get stats like "Which app is eating up my resources" etc.

For php-apache based server, **Munin** is an easy to use tool. But I wasn't able to find an alternate for Django. Any suggestions?